# Why can't i print environment variables in bash?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, hardhat

I can print variables using `console.log`, but can't find the variable in `printenv` and `echo $variable`.

This is the `.env` file:

```
SEPOLIA_RPC_URL=https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/SYu8cyWG0EOfcfZVehXUoPMXW91om6Hd
```

this the `test.js` file

```js
require("dotenv").config();

function main() {
    console.log(process.env.SEPOLIA_RPC_URL);
}
main();
```

Output:

```
blue@DESKTOP-A6GBG6O:~/solidity/hardhat-sss$ node test.js
https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/SYu8cyWG0EOfcfZVehXUoPMXW91om6Hd
blue@DESKTOP-A6GBG6O:~/solidity/hardhat-sss$ echo $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL

blue@DESKTOP-A6GBG6O:~/solidity/hardhat-sss$
```

Comment: Environment variables are inherited by child processes. Setting an environment variable doesn't affect the parent process.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. What is your question?

Comment: @jabaa why cant i get an output thru ```echo``` command? Sorry for the poorly constructed question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct.
When you are mentioning the require(dotenv) it will pick up the .env file present the directory and your variable will be available as I can see in node test.js the output is there.
But when you are using echo it will pick the ENV variables from ~/.bashrc (typically) and not your .env file, that is why the output is empty.

Comment: How do i get result by using echo?

Comment: @rvhj Please don't ask follow up questions in comments. Your question was: _"why cant i get an output thru `echo` command?"_

Comment: How do i ask follow up question? Only other option i found was to add an answer.

I have edited the question now